# How are values tracked with the 'for el in sequence' syntax?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to grasp what mechanism is keeping track of values being returned to the sum() function in the following:

```
def narcissisticNumber(value):
    return value == sum(int(x) ** len(str(value)) for x in str(value))
```

From what I see, x ** y is being calculated for each character in the value string - however, since the 'for char in str' construct is within the sum function, the result of each of these computations is being returned to sum(). The return value of sum() accounts for all iterations, and I would like to know how sum() was able to track all the return values of the x ** y expression.

I am using Python 3.7.4. Coming from Java, I understand the function does not follow best practices, I would just like to know how it works in terms of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is a Generator:

> Generators are a simple and powerful tool for creating iterators. They
>   are written like regular functions but use the yield statement
>   whenever they want to return data. Each time next() is called, the
>   generator resumes where it left-off (it remembers all the data values
>   and which statement was last executed)

Check here for better understanding: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way of understanding it better would be to break it down to a more *readable* format:

```
def narcissisticNumber(value):
    listOfValues = []
    lenOfValue = len(str(value))

    # Iterate through each character in your string
    for x in str(value):
        # Get the int-value of that character
        # then raise it to the length of your string
        xRaiseToLength = int(x) ** lenOfValue

        # Append that value to your final list
        listOfValues.append(xRaiseToLength)

    # Compute the sum of the list using sum()
    sumOfValues = sum(listOfValues)

    return value == sumOfValues
```

References:

[sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

Okey lets break it into parts:

1. `str(value)` is casting `value` into a string (`str`)
2. `len(str(value))` is getting the length of this string
3. `... for x in str(value)` is a generator expression. It will assign to x each element in `str(value)` (this is, each character) and evaluate the first clause. To simplify this, you can think that it returns an array. It actually doesn't, but conceptually yopu can think of it like that. It is actually creating a special construct that can be iterated over and that evaluates each element when they are requested, so it is way more memory efficent that creating an array.
4. `int(x)` is casting `x` (which is each of the characters of the string) into an integer (`int`).
5. `int(x) ** len(str(value))` is calculating x to the power of the length of the complete string.
6. `sum` is a fucntion that accepts any iterable construct (in this case a generator, but it could be an array of some sort) and adds its elements.

So in conclussion, if you do `narcissisticNumber(123)` it will return `1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 8 + 27 = 36`.